# Does Patibhakti lead to Moksha?

Tags: advaita, moksha, bhakti, dvaita, grihastha

Pati is a jivatma, not paramatma. What systems of thought say that having bhakti for jivatmas is a valid way to Moksha? Could Swamibhakti, patibhakti, or bhakti for characters like Bharat, etc lead to Moksha?

Comment: I think it's the karma associated with bhakti. There are many stories. A housewife who served her husband, a butcher who served his family, famous Shravan who died for parents. Not sure if they achieved moksha but they are considered great souls.

Comment: There is a verse that is translated as “the husband is god,friend(bandhu) and guru for his wife”..